# Highchart multiple stacked xaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to "stack" multiple xAxis to achieve something similar to this but i am being stuck : [image]

Can I do that with Highchart only or do I need Highstock ? If so is it a bar chart for each series on a different xAxis ?

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: You could try a scatter plot with plot bands for each of the stages, but you would have to manipulate the data such that each data point within a stage had the same Y value.

Comment: You can also think about using columnrange chart type with inverted axes. Here you can see simple example how it can work with Highcharts

Comment: Thanks ! I will try that. @GrzegorzBlachliński I don't see any link.